# Unable to style a box created by a custom template

Tags: css, wordpress

I've created a twentyfourteen child theme by using the One-click Child Theme plugin.  Then I created a custom template called "custom-table" by copying page.php in the parent theme directory to custom-table.php, also in the parent theme directory.

Next I changed the header in the new Custom Table  template to

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: Custom Table
```

so it shows up in the Template dropdown under Page Attributes for a new  page.

Next I created a new page, "Table1," and selected Custom Table from the Template dropdown.

Next I modified the custom-table.php template to create a simple box:

```
<div id="box123"></div>
```

I can see this box ok in the source for the Table1 page, but I'm unable to style the box. I've put:

```
div#box123 {
       width: 200px;
       height: 150px;
       background-color: red;
}
```

in the child style.css but that doesn't work. And I've put the above style block in the parent style.css.  That doesn't work either.

So where should I put the styling for this box?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: is your css rule maybe inside a media query?

Comment: Is your site live? I'll look at it in my browser

Comment: Johannes: no media query. LOTUSMS: That would be great!  The site is at http://steve2.wpengine.com/.  You can get to the backend with USERNAME: steve2  PASS: Early@237

Comment: Are you trying to make the #box123 div (bg = green) appear on this page: `http://steve2.wpengine.com/` ?  Or, how are you viewing the `custom-table.php` page?

Comment: The page that has #box123 is Table1, which you can see from the dashboard at **Pages | All Pages**. When I created this page I selected **Custom Table** from the Template dropdown.  It's this template, custom-table.php that has the HTML to create #box123. You can view the Table1 page by selecting it from dashboard  **Pages | All Pages** and then selecting **View**, or by putting its permalink - **http://steve2.wpengine.com/?page_id=7** - into a browser. The parent theme's style.css tries to set bg=green and the child theme's style.css tries to set bg=red, but neither work..

Answer (score 0):

Your `css` should go in the child theme `style.css`.

However, inspecting the page there is no css file loaded at all. I suspect your problem is you're not using the `get_header()` function in your template file. You'll need this for WordPress to create the `<head>` tags and everything that goes inside it including the main style file.

In the 2014 theme at line 14 is where you'll find `get_header()`. Make sure it's in your page template file too.